# Use of tf.data.Dataset with Keras input layer on Tensorflow 2.0

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0

I'm experimenting with `TensorFlow` 2.0 alpha and I've found that it works as expected when using `Numpy` arrays but when `tf.data.Dataset` is used, an input dimension error appears. I'm using the iris dataset as the simplest example to demonstrate this:

```
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler, OneHotEncoder

import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python import keras

iris = datasets.load_iris()

scl = StandardScaler()
ohe = OneHotEncoder(categories='auto')
data_norm = scl.fit_transform(iris.data)
data_target = ohe.fit_transform(iris.target.reshape(-1,1)).toarray()
train_data, val_data, train_target, val_target = train_test_split(data_norm, data_target, test_size=0.1)
train_data, test_data, train_target, test_target = train_test_split(train_data, train_target, test_size=0.2)


train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((train_data, train_target))
train_dataset.batch(32)

test_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((test_data, test_target))
test_dataset.batch(32)

val_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((val_data, val_target))
val_dataset.batch(32)

mdl = keras.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Dense(16, input_dim=4, activation='relu'),
    keras.layers.Dense(8, activation='relu'),
    keras.layers.Dense(8, activation='relu'),
    keras.layers.Dense(3, activation='sigmoid')]
)

mdl.compile(
    optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(0.01),
    loss=keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy,
    metrics=[keras.metrics.categorical_accuracy]
    )

history = mdl.fit(train_dataset, epochs=10, steps_per_epoch=15, validation_data=val_dataset)
```

and I get the following error:

```
ValueError: Error when checking input: expected dense_16_input to have shape (4,) but got array with shape (1,)
```

assuming that the dataset has only one dimension. If I pass input_dim=1 I get a different error:

```
InvalidArgumentError: Incompatible shapes: [3] vs. [4]
     [[{{node metrics_5/categorical_accuracy/Equal}}]] [Op:__inference_keras_scratch_graph_8223]
```

What is the proper way to use `tf.data.Dataset` on a `Keras` model with `Tensorflow 2.0`?

Comment: It seems like your sample code has some formatting/syntax errors (the variable `dataset` is not declared, and there is a stray `return` keyword). Can you fix this and update the question?

Comment: Whats is the shape of your `data_target` after the hot encoding step?

Comment: Yes, it was more of an example. Fixed the code. The shape of data_target is (3,1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few changes should fix your code. The `batch()` dataset transformation does not occur in-place, so you need to return the new datasets. Secondly, you should also add a `repeat()` transformation, so that the dataset continues to output examples after all of the data has been seen.

```
...

train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((train_data, train_target))
train_dataset = train_dataset.batch(32)
train_dataset = train_dataset.repeat()

val_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((val_data, val_target))
val_dataset = val_dataset.batch(32)
val_dataset = val_dataset.repeat()
...
```

You also need to add the argument for `validation_steps` in the `model.fit()` function:

```
history = mdl.fit(train_dataset, epochs=10, steps_per_epoch=15, validation_data=val_dataset, validation_steps=1)
```

For your own data, you may need to adjust the `batch_size` for the validation dataset and `validation_steps`, such that the validation data is only cycled once during each step.